# Как обрезать текстовый файл до нужной длины? C++

Tags: c++, fstream

Точнее.. Нужно обрезать не сам файл, а сам текст в файле.
Предположим, есть test.txt, в нем текст из 500 символов. Мне нужно оставить 20 символов.
С текстом работаю так:
fstream short("test.txt");
Как-то можно удалить все символы, начиная с 21 и до конца?

Comment: Решение на WinAPI не предлагать?

Comment: Все таки вам нужно файл обрезать, или исходный файл должен остаться без изменений, а поток должен показать eof после 20 символов?

Comment: @Lemondik: А как тот код, который читает файл, узнает, что информация обрезана, если файл продолжается дальше?

Answer (score 2):

Ну, можно перезаписать, создавая файл заново, а можно воспользоваться функцией `chsize` - что удобнее.

Результат - файл нужного размера.

Если это не то, что вам нужно - поясните детальнее и однозначнее.

Answer (score 0):

Помечать что блок удален, потом когда таких блоков накопится много можно делать дефрагментацию. 
P.S. А вообще лучше используйте СУБД.